# Error 500 when executing Flask Webserver

Tags: pi-3, sqlite

Straight to the point. I'm using flask web server to build my monitoring garden. with this tutorial: 
https://www.instructables.com/id/From-Data-to-Graph-a-Web-Jorney-With-Flask-and-SQL/

finally, I made it with following step by step this tutorial. Using flask as web server and some how, the result i got were slightly different. I'm totally sure, same as the author for every aspect (database, code).

FYI, the final result must be displaying 2 historical chart images based on my database. and sure mine was displaying it perfectly but why its only display 1 chart ? the humidity chart. and when i check the messages i got  error 500 http on my terminal while the other GET method were 200  when flask running

[image: Error 500 HTTP GET]

[image: Result on Web]

I don't understand whats the problem, the humidity data were perfectly displayed but why the temperature data were not. in fact humidity and temperature is on same table.

[this is the link of python flask app](https://github.com/Mjrovai/RPI-Flask-SQLite/blob/master/dhtWebHist/appDhtWebHist.py#L121)

[this is the link for html index](https://github.com/Mjrovai/RPI-Flask-SQLite/blob/master/dhtWebHist/templates/index_gage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, find the line with Temperature and remove the degree symbol so it looks like this "Temperature [C]". Could be your version of python but whatever the reason, it's unable to decode that symbol. Try searching "python can't decode 0xc2" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: thank you so much ! yes after i remove the symbol degree its work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I see this kind of error often, when I use Python code that is written for Python 3 with an Python 2 interpreter / Runtime (or vice versa). They change the way String literals are interpreted when printing/serializing (asscii, UTF-8). Please compare your python installation with that of the original author. Is is the same? I'm pretty sure that's the problem.